# C# XMLTextWriter include default Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml

How can I define a default namespace in XML using the `XMLTextWriter`?

I want my XML to look like this:

```
<myXml xmlns:nss="http://my/location/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://my/location/">

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("myXml");
xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "nss", null, statusNamespace);
xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, xsiSchemaNamespace);
```

How can I get the xmlns default without any prefix?

If I add the following line additionally, I get `the prefix cannot be redefined from to "http://my/location/"`

```
xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", null, null, statusNamespace);
```

Comment: `WriteAttributeString(null, "xmlns", null, statusNamespace)` ?

Comment: No, I still get the same error message! The prefix cannot be redefined with the same start element tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally prefer to use the overloads which accept namespaces directly, rather than manually trying to apply namespaces via attributes.

This code:

```
var myWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create("Blah1.xml");
myWriter.WriteStartDocument();
myWriter.WriteStartElement("myXml", "http://my/location/");
myWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "nss", null, "http://my/location/");
myWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null,
         "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
myWriter.Close();
```

Generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myXml xmlns:nss="http://my/location/" 
mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://my/location/" />
```

(With spaces added for readability)